# The generation of Scree Plot for Hierarchical Cluster in R / ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I generate a dendrogram with hclust() and now I want to generate a scree plot from this code:
[How to generate a Scree Plot for Hierarchical Cluster in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42334419/how-to-generate-a-scree-plot-for-hierarchical-cluster-in-r/51223656#51223656)

```
> ggplot(myhclust$height %>%
+            as.tibble() %>%
+            add_column(groups = length(myhclust$height):1) %>%
+            rename(height=value),
+        aes(x=groups, y=height)) +
+     geom_point() +
+     geom_line()
```

When I try to run this code I have this error message:

```
Error in is.data.frame(.data) : 
  argument ".data" is missing, with no default
In addition: Warning message:
The `x` argument of `as_tibble()` can't be missing as of tibble 3.0.0.
```

I try to solve this problem with my data but this is not the solution. Do you have any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: Since the example in the linked thread works as expected, we should look at your data set to troubleshoot why you're receiving this error message.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data or a subset of the data you are using, then pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg